# How to allow img tag?

Tags: ckeditor, wysiwyg, fckeditor

I have created my custom image plugin that insert only external images. But if I disable the default image plugin then the img tag doesn't appear in the form. Why ?

This is my plugin:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'img',
{
    init: function( editor )
    {
        editor.addCommand( 'insertImg',
            {
                exec : function( editor )
                {    
                    var imgurl=prompt("Insert url image");
                    editor.insertHtml('<img src="'+imgurl+'" />');
                }
            });
        editor.ui.addButton( 'img',
        {

            label: 'Insert img',
            command: 'insertImg',
            icon: this.path + 'images/aaa.png'
        } );
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to integrate your plugin with ACF - Advanced Content Filter which was introduced in CKEditor 4.1.

Here's a useful guide - [Plugins integration with ACF](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_integration_with_acf).

Basically, you're introducing a feature to the editor. This feature needs to tell editor how it is represented in HTML, so what should be allowed when this feature is enabled.

In the simplest case, when you have a button, which executes a command you just need to define   two properties of the [`CKEDITOR.feature`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.feature) interface: `allowedContent` and `requiredContent`.

E.g.:

```
editor.addCommand( 'insertImg', {
    requiredContent: 'img[src]', // Minimal HTML which this feature requires to be enabled.
    allowedContent: 'img[!src,alt,width,height]', // Maximum HTML which this feature may create.
    exec: function( editor ) {    
        var imgurl=prompt("Insert url image");
        editor.insertHtml('<img src="'+imgurl+'" />');
    }
} );
```

And now, when this button will be added to the toolbar, feature will be automatically enabled and images will be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You set wrong command name in your addButton config. You need to set:

```
editor.addCommand( 'insertImg', {
         ...
     }
);
```

as well as the name of `command` config in `editor.ui.addButton()`

**UPD:**
some fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kreeg/2Jzpr/522/

Comment: I created some fiddle for you. Everything's ok:  http://jsfiddle.net/kreeg/2Jzpr/522/